# Help! Need someone to do some composition for a game ASAP. 

Tags: work, composition

Hi all,

Hope this ok to post here, but I'm kind of desperate lol

Need someone to come up with some short looping music BG (6 x 30 secs) based upon variations of a main theme tune. Its a flash based game and I've been given the main theme tune so far and they'd like some variations to play in the background of the levels. Hoping they can give me the Logic file I've been asking for asap too! But may have to work with just the mixed theme track.

Some of the variations will be based on a 'wizardy' feel. So any experience of styles of that ilk would be great. I need 2 examples by Friday, and the rest can follow a week later.
Nothing too crazy. Not after massive orchestration here.

Shout me up asap if you're interested and can deliver, so we can discuss terms etc.

Cheers,

PS I can email the theme and in game footage if you need it!
Andy

Answer (score 2):

Hi Andy,

If you send me over the theme and game footage i will take a look at if you if you want! You can see some of my previous work on my website www.juliancole.co.uk.

My email is julian@juliancole.co.uk

Thanks in advance.

Julian

Comment: You have mail. Hopefully lol your out of office was on though! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Andy, check me out at : www.markus-schmidt-music.com, I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andy,

Not sure if you still need someone for this but you can check out my site at www.simonashdown.co.uk - I have worked on projects for the BBC, Channel 4, HBO and Sky.

email direct at syashdown@hotmail.com

Thanks